# Mediation analysis with curvilinear mediator and categorical predictors

Tags: mediation

I am currently conducting analyses where I wish to investigate how one variable (M) mediates the association between SES (3-level categorical variable) and a measure of health (continuous variable). The association between M and health is curvilinear, meaning that both low and high levels of M is associated with increased health problems.

Any suggestions on how to go about achieving this? I have studied the literature on mediation, but haven't been able to find an approach which seems suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a purist's answer, but it would probably make things easier on you and your audience if you categorized M into 3 or 5 levels.  Then it would be a straightforward anova task to show how different combinations of M and SES are linked with different health scores.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure, but I think the [mediation package for R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mediation/index.html) can do what you want as it covers a wide range of models that can act as the mediator (I am not totally sure how it works with the categorial variable, but you will find out).

Have a look at the [nice vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mediation/vignettes/mediation.pdf) or the homepage of [Kosuke Imai for some papers on the package](http://imai.princeton.edu/software/mediation.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, as you hint at, there are problems with categorical variables when the relationship with the outcome is not linear. It only analyzes the 0 and 1 level of the predictor variable, and when there is a different association at different values of predictor, it will not work.